# reading user input in shell script

Tags: python, shell

While being in loop, I am reading user input as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
    echo $line
    python find_entity.py $line
    read -p "Enter your name : " choice
    echo $choice
done < "q0.txt"
```

but still it does not ask for user input choice, rather writes `True` and just continue. What is wrong here?

Comment: Change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash -x` and look at the output...

Comment: @FredrikPihl: thanks but still now change

Comment: The purpose of the `-x` flag is to turn on debugging so that you'll see what your parameters expands to. Look at the output and verify that `$line` etc contains the expected values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash user prompt while reading file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422476/bash-user-prompt-while-reading-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will not cover all the possible use cases, but please try if this simple solution suffices for yours

```
...
read -p "Enter your name : " choice < /dev/tty
...
```

what happens, what was pointed to you... is that `read` reads from standard input, and you have *globally* redirected `stdin` to the file `q0.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply do:

```
for line in `cat q0.txt`
do
    echo $line
    python find_entity.py $line
    read -p "Enter your name : " choice
    echo $choice
done
```

Your code does not ask for any input because you are redirecting the content of q0.txt to the standard input, and the "read" statement gets the choice variable from the same place.